# Cannot cast IStorageItem to StorageFile

Tags: c#, .net, windows, universal

The following code will not compile because IsOfType is not accepted as a method on item. The documentation states:

> When this method completes successfully, it returns an IStorageItem
>   that represents the specified file or folder. If the specified file or
>   folder is not found, this method returns null instead of raising an
>   exception.
>
> To work with the returned item, call the IsOfType method of the
>   IStorageItem interface to determine whether the item is a file or a
>   folder. Then cast the item to a StorageFolder or StorageFile.

```
private async void RestoreData(string fileName)
    {
        StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        var item = folder.TryGetItemAsync(fileName);
        if (item == null)
        {
            existingData = false;
        }
        if (item.IsOfType(StorageItemTypes.File))
        {
            await ReadDataAsync(item as StorageFile);
            existingData = true;
        }
        existingData = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing `await` keyword to await the result of an async method - in this case you should write something like this:

```
var item = await folder.TryGetItemAsync(fileName);
```

Thanks to that `item` is of type `IStorageItem` whereas in your code it was of type `IAsyncOperation<IStorageItem>`.

By [convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#), all async methods have `Async` suffix and you need to await result to inspect it.

**Tip:**

In most IDEs when you hover mouse on `var` keyword, a type of a variable will be displayed - that makes it much easier to find the error.

Comment: Doh. I did notice that the type was IAsyncOperation<IStorageItem> but I didn't realise this was a clue that the await was missing.

Comment: Good that I could help. Asyncs are quite important part of C#, I recommend reading about them - [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx) covers the basics.